# which way you prefer to communicate between ros1 image stream through ros2(not local network)?

Tags: websocket, stream, webrtc, ros

"I have been exploring various methods to set up a system where I need to stream camera footage from Server 1, which is equipped with a camera and ROS1(camera topic), to Server 2, running ROS2. These servers are on different networks. My research has led me to consider three potential solutions:

ROS Bridge
WebRTC
WebSocket
However, I am uncertain which method would be the most effective for achieving this. Could you provide some advice on the best approach to establish this connection?"

Not sure which way is the best to solve this.

Comment: That depends a little on what you want to do with the video stream on server 2. If it's just for watching, then definitely webrtc. See this comparison I wrote: https://transitiverobotics.com/blog/streaming-video-from-robots